# wait for user input to reply on a facebook bot using Node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots

What I need to do is make my bot after replying to something wait for user response so that he can reply with a flow ending messege Example:

**User**: clicks the Get Started button

**Bot**: I can help you with the following (Payment) (option2) (option3)

**User**: clicks Payment

**Bot**: Can you please enter the bill number

**User**:3922509234

.............................

**Bot**:Ok thank you, your payment will be processed

this is how the facebook app comunicates with the bot

```
 app.post('/webhook', function(request, response) {
 var data = request.body;
 if(data.object == 'page'){
  data.entry.forEach(function(pageEntry){
   pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function (messagingEvent) {
       if(messagingEvent.message){
         console.log("MESSAGE---------------------> ",messagingEvent);
       var messageInfo = functions.reciveMessage(messagingEvent);
       console.log("MESSAGEINFO ", messageInfo);
       evaluateMessage(messageInfo);
      }
       if(messagingEvent.postback){
         console.log("POSTBACK--------------------> ",messagingEvent);
        var postBackInfo = functions.recivePostBack(messagingEvent);
        evaluatePostBack(postBackInfo);
       }
     });
   });
  response.sendStatus(200);
 }
});
```

This is where the user's input is evaluated for keywords

```
function evaluateMessage(messageInfo, type) {
if(functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'Pagar')||
 functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'pagar')||
 functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'Factura')||
 functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'factura')){
  var message = functions.sendTextMessage(messageInfo.senderId, "Por 
   favor ingresa el numero de tu contrato");
   callSendAPI(message);
    }
   }
```

The messageInfo is check if contains the keyWord then returns the message to the user.

How do i make the bot wait for user input so that he can reply

**Im using Node.Js with express not any bot building platform please help**

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way of doing this though there might be a better way a made a global variable

```
var verifier = {
  origin:null,
  state:false
};
```

then when it enters the message validator and modifies the json with a sort of token and sets the state to true

```
function evaluateMessage(messageInfo) {

 if (functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'Pagar')||
   functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'pagar')|| 
   functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'Factura')|| 
   functions.isWordContain(messageInfo.senderMessage,'factura')){

 var message = functions.sendTextMessage(messageInfo.senderId, "Por favor 
   ingresa el numero de tu contrato");

  verifier.origin = 'pagoFactura';
  verifier.state = true;

   callSendAPI(message);
    }
  }
```

later where the messages enter I just ask if that state is true and which is the origin and depending if its one or the other I send a message

```
 app.post('/webhook', function(request, response) {

  var data = request.body;
  if(data.object == 'page'){
    data.entry.forEach(function(pageEntry){
      pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function (messagingEvent) {
          if(messagingEvent.message){
            if(verifier.state == false){
              console.log("MESSAGE---------------------> ",messagingEvent);
              var messageInfo = functions.reciveMessage(messagingEvent);
              console.log("MESSAGEINFO ", messageInfo);
              evaluateMessage(messageInfo);
            }else {
              console.log("verifierOrigin ", verifier.origin);
              var messageInfo = functions.reciveMessage(messagingEvent);
              switch (verifier.origin) {
                case 'pagoFactura':
                var message = functions.sendTextMessage(messageInfo.senderId, 
                   "Gracias su pago se a procesado exitosamente");
                callSendAPI(message);
                  break;
                default:

              }
            }
          }
          if(messagingEvent.postback){
            console.log("POSTBACK--------------------> ",messagingEvent);
            var postBackInfo = functions.recivePostBack(messagingEvent);
            evaluatePostBack(postBackInfo);
          }
       });
     });
     response.sendStatus(200);
   }
 });
```

**If someone finds a better way please comment also I know this is not the best way this is just for testing purposes**